# oracle db stored procedure syntax

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

```
create or replace procedure procOne(sid IN number,sname IN varchar,fee IN number)
as
begin
   insert into student 
   values(sid,sname,fee)
end;
/
```

I'm getting as procedure created with compilation errors.

what is the error in it?

Comment: "oracle show stored procedure compilation errors" in google will tell you how to get the error message.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you want someone to take your question seriously, please spend some time in crafting it.  Read this - http://sscce.org/ and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

missing semicolon

```
create or replace procedure procOne(sid IN number,sname IN varchar,fee IN number)
as
begin
   insert into student 
   values(sid,sname,fee);
end;
/
```